# Running code only for tests in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to rotate camera screen to left when any tests using that otherwise keep it rotateRight.

Below is Main schema code

```
 UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

But I want to change it to landscapeLeft when test schema using this

Point me right direction to keep some condition.

I'm using Swift 4, Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a UI test, you should be able to do the following at the top of your test method:

```
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .landscapeLeft
```

Comment: my tests are KIF tests so not possible to keep in tests. So trying to keep some condition in MainSchema(Development Pod)